# Calculate which app use more internal space among my link2sd moved apps

Tags: link2sd

That's my problem:
I use, happily, link2sd and after installing a lot of apps I got my internal memory full again.

Now I'd like to delete apps but I have no clues on how internal space they use since I've moved them with link2sd...

Any apps/hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Disk Usage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage) app. It draws nice graphical diagram with directories proportional to their size. There's a dedicated lookup option for apps too.

Comment: Will it help me in my particular task (link2sd, internal and ext2 memory)?

Comment: Yes (based on what you've asked in question). It does nothing other than disk usage (by app, directory, file). Its a little app. Install & see by yourself. At the time of opening, choose `App Storage`.

Answer (score 0):

Link2SD comes with awesome filter settings and sort size.

So in filter settings choose 'Internal memory' and in Sort choose 'By data size'.

This way link2sd will show you all the programs that are in internal memory in descending order of their data size.

Comment: Mmmmh maybe I was unclear: all my apps are linked to sd but I imagine a "small part" of the app remains in the internal memory, because I see that it is full anyway. What I'm looking for is something to understand how much of a linked to sd app remains in internal... :)

Comment: The small part you're talking about is the 'data'. Link2sd moves everything except data. That's why I told you to sort size by data size.